# How to change colors of 3D parametric plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, color, piecewise

I have a 3D iterative plot, where each iteration (1,2,3) is represented by equation of piecewise linear function. I am trying to change the colors of plot, to get for every iteration (piecewise function) different color.

Here is my plot and code what I use for plotting

[image]

```
Show[Map[ParametricPlot3D[{x, maxlines[x, iterpairs[[#]]], #}, {x, 0, 
     1},BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 3}}] &,
   Range[3]]]
```

I was trying to add as parameter `ColorFunction`, but it didnt work.

```
ColorFunction->"Rainbow"
```

Does anyone know which parameter should I add, to change the colors of this plot? Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like `PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][...]`, e.g. (You did not show what your `maxlines` is, so I'm using random numbers as example)

```
Show[Map[ParametricPlot3D[{x, x + RandomReal[], #}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][#/3]] &, Range[3]]]
```

[image]